# Does a symmetric current distribution $\vec{J}(\vec r)$ simplify multipole moments of vector potential?

Tags: electromagnetism, multipole-expansion

For a spherically symmetric charge distribution, $\rho(\vec r)=\rho(r)$, all higher-order multipole moments except the monopole term vanish.

Does a similar thing happen for the multipoles of a spherically symmetric current distribution $\vec{J}(\vec r)=J(r)\hat{r}$ or distributions with some other high degree of symmetry?

I do not think so. Because the monopole moment always vanishes. If all higher-order moments vanish too, then the vector potential (thus, the magnetic field) will be identically zero. But is there any simplification?

Comment: You'd probably want a cylindrically symmetric current distribution as the lowest order term in a magnetic expansion is usually the dipole term for reasons you've already stated.

Comment: @Triatticus In that case, do the moments of order higher than the dipole vanish?

Answer (score 0):

The magnetic field for a spherically symmetric current is in fact zero.

Comment: Welcome to [Physics.SE]!  I think this answer is correct, but you should probably elaborate on why it is true and be more explicit about how it relates to the question.  It's a little confusing on its own.